# Drop down menu from action bar - allowing drag and drop icons to be drawn to screen

Tags: java, android, menu

as the title suggests I'm trying to add code to my app which allows the user to click on an item in the action bar menu which then unfolds a drop down menu (spinner class?) containing a few options such as lamp, tv etc. - each with an icon. The user will then be able to select one of these and drag and drop the icon (or an image representing the icon) to the canvas where it is then drawn. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring  to the ActionBar overflow menu items, then you would have to take a look at the code for the ActionBar in the framework and extend it in your application, but that would firstly require quite a hassle and secondly would break compatibility when changes are made to the ActionBar in new versions of Android.

Also, this goes completely away from what the ActionBar is intended to be. You should only have actions in the overflow menu, not contain elements that directly interact with the Activity content. It's just wrong. Consider redesigning your UI so that you implement the requested featured inside the content view, not on the ActionBar.

Comment: Ah ok, I've decided to simply make the action bar change the drawing mode to "appliance" then when the user touches - bring up a dialog to get information about what appliance and therefore what icon to draw.

Comment: Yes, that's a good example of a better UI design. Nicely done.